# what does _safeMint() do under the hood?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, nft, hardhat

The following is some stripped down sample code which I am using to formulate my question. This pertains to the Youtube Video by Patrick Collins entitled:  **How to make NFT Art with On-Chain Metadata | FULL HARDHART / JS TUTORIAL! (w/ Polygon & Opensea)**

```
contract RandomSVG is ERC721URIStorage, VRFConsumerBase {
    ....
    ....    
    function create() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        requestId = requestRandomness(keyhash, fee);
        ...
    ...
    }
 

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomNumber)
        internal
        override
    {
       
    ...
    ...
        _safeMint(nftOwner, tokenId); 
    ...
    }

}
```

The RandomSVG is a contract that will create random NFTs.

**Question 1 :**
I read the documentation but i'm still unable to understand. What does the `_safeMint()` function exactly do ?

**Question 2:** At what point in the contract should the `_safeMint()` function be called ?

In his example, Patrick is using the `_safeMint()` function inside the `fulfillRandomness()` callback. Why is the `_safeMint()` called even before the Image has been created ? Shouldn't it be called After the TokenURI has been created ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

_safeMint() is used along with [IERC721Receiver](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721Receiver) that checks if you are sending the minted token to a Contract that is capable to manage NFTs or not. This is to prevent tokens to be lost.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Javva. What does it mean to "mint" a token or NFT? in the case of NFT's, is it the act of creating an NFT out of thin air ?

Comment: Exactly mint the token is the act of creating a token, assign an ID, and image, etc.

Comment: Note that it is fine to send NFTs to smart contract wallets such as [Gnosis Safe](https://gnosis-safe.io/), even if they don't implement the `IERC721Receiver` interface. Refer to this [Q&A](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/124516/safetransferfrom-of-erc721-not-working-when-transfering-nft-to-a-safe-address) for more details.